# Integer doesn't update in inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, integer

I'm trying to create a statue where you can refill your mana. Here is my code:

```
public int mana = 5;

void Start()
{
    mana = 5;
}

void Update()
{
    if(mana < 0)
    {
        mana = 0;
    }
    if(mana > 5)
    {
        mana = 5;
    }
}

public void refillMana()
{
    mana = 5;
    if(mana == 5)
    {
        Debug.Log("Mana is refilled");
    }
}
```

I have this in a script and then a seperate script calls `refillMana()` using an event but my mana int doesn't update in the inspector and I can't use my spells. But the console still says "Mana is refilled".

I tried using the statue by activating the UnityEvent and I expected the inspector to say that my mana was 5 but it still said 0 and I couldn't use my spells.

Note: in the past it did work but only when I hadn't entered a load zone, I tried to fix that but then I got this problem.

Comment: Put the Inspector into Debug mode and see what you get.  Updated values by default do not show up in the inspector.  At the top right of the Inspector window click the Gear icon and select Debug view.

Comment: @jiveturkey that's not true .. as soon as the variable is serialized in the Inspector it is always visible and also on runtime updating to the actual current state ... Debug mode is only needed if you also want to see private non-serialized fields values

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the `refillMana` of the correct component instance you are looking at..?

Comment: "mana" is a variable of the statue.  Does the player character have its own mana value?  It looks to me like this code is refilling the statue's mana, not the player's.